# dotnet ef database update fails

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Within docker container I am trying to run the following command but getting an error

```
dotnet ef database update --startup-project ./Insta.Mvc/Insta.Mvc.csproj --project Insta.Infra.Data --context InstaDbContext;
```

The error is:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.424/Microsoft.Common.targets(127,3): error MSB4024: The imported project file "/dotnetapp/Insta.Infra.Data/obj/Insta.Infra.Data.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets" could not be loaded. Unexpected end tag. Line 26, position 6. [/dotnetapp/Insta.Infra.Data/Insta.Infra.Data.csproj]

Comment: It is telling you where to look for the error. Check file `/dotnetapp/Insta.Infra.Data/obj/Insta.Infra.Data.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets`, line 26, column 6. Does it look like valid XML?

Comment: Yes it is a valid file. Project is running fine in debug mode. It has this issue in docker container